# Calling a function within a listener function

Tags: c#, function, listener

I'm new to the C# world and I am trying to call another function inside a listener using this code below:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listener = new GestureListener(100);
        listener.onGesture += listener_onGesture;
        controller = new Controller(listener);
    }

    static void listener_onGesture(Gesture gesture)
    {
        string gestures = "";

        foreach (Gesture.Direction direction in gesture.directions) {
            gestures = direction.ToString();
        }

        int howManyFingers = gesture.fingers;

        if (gestures == "Left" && howManyFingers == 2) {
            test();
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("gestured " + gestures + " with " + gesture.fingers + " fingers.");
        }
    }

    private void test()
    {
        pdf.gotoNextPage();
    }
```

However, it does not seem to work when i do that. The error it gives me on the line **test();** is:

*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'LeapDemoTest.Form1.test()'*

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this because `listener_onGesture` is a static method -- meaning, the method is not associated with a given instance of your class. However, `test` is an instance method -- so it is scoped to the specific instance.

I see three options, depending on the scope of "pdf", but I recommend option 1:

- Make `listener_onGesture` an instance method (remove the `static` keyword)
- Make `test` a static method -- this will only work if `pdf` is also a static member.
- Somewhat hackish -- find the `Form` instance that invoked the event by inspecting the `sender`'s properties and invoke the `test` method on that instance.

Answer (score 1):

`listener_onGesture` probably shouldn't be static.  You want to access instance fields within this method, and you appear to be calling it from within an instance of the application (`Form1_Load`, where you currently reference it from, is not a static method).  By removing the `static` modifier from that method you will then be able to call a non-static method.

Comment: Thanks for helping out as well, Servy!